# How do I express a JOIN and GROUP BY query in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
SELECT sector.sector, count(*) 
FROM reports, organization, sector 
WHERE reports.org_id = organization.id
    AND organization.id = sector.org_id
GROUP BY sector.sector;
```

I'm honestly not even sure where to begin expressing this GROUP BY and JOIN in sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
db.query(func.count(Sector.sector), Sector.sector).\
    join(Organzation).join(Report).\
    group_by(Sector.sector).all()
```

I was able to represent it as the following expression. My earlier efforts were failing because I needed to `db.rollback()` my awkward failed attempts.